# using TypeSccript should I export the store as well from the store file?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I'm using TypeScript in conjunction with Redux.

I'm following the [docs](https://react-redux.js.org/tutorials/typescript-quick-start) and they don't export the store, only the two types mentioned below:

```
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
// Inferred type: {posts: PostsState, comments: CommentsState, users: UsersState}
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
```

I need to use the store in the Provider, should I export and import the store as usual or there is another way to do it when using TypeScript?

Answer (score 2):

Those are the steps for additional code you have to write for using TypeScript. It only is about types you have to write, not about runtime code. So you have to follow the normal quick start tutorial just as well - meaning: yes, you also have to export the store or you will not be able to ever interact with it.